# Excel VBA - clear cells above and below cell with text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for some help please with some VBA.

Let's say I have a range of cells (B4:B12), so if I input data in a cell within the range I would like to clear all cells in the same range except for the cell in which I inputed the data. So that I can only have 1 cell with data in the range.

So if B5 had data and I inputed data in B7 then B5 would clear, then if i entered data in B10 then B7 would clear...

I hope there is a solution as I have been trying to find an answer for the past couple of hours.

Comment: WorsheetChange event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel

Comment: @QHarr Wor**k**sheet :)

Comment: @JohnyL Yes. I missed the timing for an edit and was too lazy to delete and re-enter. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Set myRange = Sh.Range("B4:B12")

'set the current cell/address/value so we don't lose them when the range is cleared
Set cell = Sh.Range(Target.address)    
value = Target

'disable/enable so this isn't called every time a cell is cleared
'clear the range then reset the to entered value
If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    myRange.Clear
    cell.value = value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Kevin, a suggested addition to your answer is to set the desired range in the worksheet as a named range (e.g. "CellsToCheck"), and then your example above compares against the named range. e.g. `If Not Intersect(Target, CellsToCheck) Is Nothing Then`. Doesn't change the functionality of what you have suggested but does remove some magic numbers (and a couple of lines of code).

Comment: thank you kevin that work great, i appreciate your help

Comment: @AJD - if it was my spreadsheet I would definitely use a named range, I only used the cell values because of the example question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use worksheet event to bevplaced in the relevant worksheet code pane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myVal As Variant

    With Range("B4:B12") ‘reference your range
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Cells) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then ‘ if changed range is one cell within the referenced one
            myVal = Target.Value ‘store changed cell value
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .ClearContents ‘ clear the content of referenced range
            Target.Value = myVal ‘ write changed cell value back
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With 
End Sub
```